Creating Planetary Rings as Seen from the Surface
I'm creating an exoplanet landscape similar to Mars but with a ring system that will include 2 rings encircling the planet.  This view will be from the surface of the planet looking skyward toward the rings and I'd like the scale to be awe-inspiring but am not sure the best way to go about constructing arcs of such immense size that suggest realistic rings.  Any suggestions?


yes, i have suggestions: please add at least one image how you want it to look like. thx.

Create circles and give them a grainy material?

You could use a Wave and Gradient node to create the concentric circles, use it as a factor between an Emission and a Transparent node, you could add a bit of Noise afterwards to make it a bit grainy:

File: 

That's terrific!  I'll give it a try.  I suppose I could just scale it up and then place my landscape model right in the middle of it and it would look very realistic as seen from the surface.  Appreciate the help.

Put it in the background behind the landscape?

Sorry but while I have the material all mapped out, I'm getting tripped up applying it to geometry and then rendering out a ring.  If I begin with a circle, it's still a far cry from an actual mesh.  When I figure that one out, I can either build it inside my landscape and scale it up or save the ring as a Blender file then append the landscape with this model.  Guess I'm still too much of a Blender novice to make that leap from material-to-model.  Too many years with early Cinema 4D modeling with drag-and-drop texturing.  Can you help a bit further on this?

I've added the file, I hope it helps, I've created a circle and give it this material

I've downloaded the file but it does not open in Blender 3.4.  Do I need Blender 4 to open it?

Try to append it (File > Append)?

I did that too, but as soon as I selected the Collection and tried to open it, Blender crashed.  However, I just installed version 4.1.1 and it Appended just fine.  So far it doesn't appear to want to upscale though and I need for it to be extra large in order to fit to scale inside this enormous landscape, but the rings look great and I thank you so much for the kind assistance and follow-up on this issue.  Geometry Nodes Rule!

Thanks, but this is not Geometry Nodes! Just Shader Editor nodes  ;)

Thanks for the clarification.  I have just one more question, these rings need to be far off in the distance above the horizon of this Mars-like planet, so the opacity of the rings must be reduced by a large factor.  They should be semi-transparent.  Any suggestion on the best way to make that happen for this model?

add a last Mix Shader just before the Output, mix the current setup with a Transparent node, play with the Factor of the Mix Shader

I've assembled your transparent node setup but unsure if I have the correct connections.   By the way, I used instead a Translucent Node since planetary rings are more translucent than transparent.  I tried to attach a screenshot, but it said there were errors attaching it so I'll describe how I hooked everything up:  The output of the new Translucent BSDF is hooked into the topmost input Shader of the new Mix Shader, while the Shader output of the original Mix Shader is hooked into the bottom Shader input of the new Mix Shader.  Finally the new Mix Shader, Shader output goes into the Surface.

Thanks for all your help with this project.  Seems it's taken on a life of its own and I'm just not that capable in Blender yet.  Anyway, I've upscaled the ring and placed it about where it should go relative to the landscape, but the render turns the ring a bright white and so far I haven't been able to get that filmy, translucent look for the ring.  Any suggestions?  By the way, I'm still not able to attach a screenshot to these posts.
